# Is there any harm in creating a "private" instance of NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using notifications to provide two-way communication between a pair of objects, where object A makes a request but may get deallocated before object B responds.

NSNotificationCenter is perfect for this, as object A can simply add itself as an observer. When object B responds, it posts a notification, and if object A has disappeared, the notification is merely ignored.

Since the notification is only intended for object A, it would be practical to set up a private instance of `NSNotificationCenter` for these notifications, instead of posting them on the `defaultCenter`. The only disadvantage would be additional memory for the NSNotificationCenter instance, but a time savings when notifications are posted on either.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can go both ways, there are no real (dis)advantages that I could think of. I usually have the notification center as an explicit dependency initialized to the shared center. That way you can isolate the notifications if you want to, but the object works out of the box:

```
@interface Observable : NSObject
@property(retain) NSNotificationCenter *radio;
@end

@implementation Observable
@synthesize radio;
- (id) init {
    [super init];
    [self setRadio:[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]];
    return self;
}
@end
```

The short answer is *do as you please*.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. In Cocoa, AppKit's NSWorkspace does [exactly this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/notificationCenter).

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter, you can just use the default notification center, and have only object A / object B listen to each other. Just ask object A to remove itself from the notification center before deallocation to prevent EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: I'm not asking if I can use defaultCenter, I know that already.

Comment: Quoting Apple documentation "Each running Cocoa program has a default notification center. You typically don’t create your own..."

Comment: My question: "Is there any harm in doing X instead of Y?" Your answer: "You can do Y."

Comment: No harm in doing so. Go right ahead. I mean, your program will not suddenly leak megs of RAM or crash for no reason if you alloc your own center, if that's what you're asking.